# Amazon EC2 license question

Tags: amazon-ec2

I would like to ask how licensing works on multiple instances? Suppose that I have an application that I bought earlier, and I have a lincese key to run it. I install this application to the basic AMI, then i enter the license key, and I boundle this instance to a new AMI. I need 5 instances from this AMI. If I run 5 instances from this AMI, then I will have 5 instances, but I have a license key for only 1 instance. So how does it work legally? I need to create 5 AMI using 5 different license key, and then create 1 instance from each AMI?

thanks for the answer

Comment: You should discuss this with the vendor from whom you bought the application.

Comment: This question is asking a legal question "So how does it work legally?" It's not about programming so is not within the scope of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the license which governs your Operating System. Here, each instance corresponds to an installation. If your license is for installation on 2 machines, then you can use the license key to run 2 instances simultaneously. Likewise, you can run only one instance if you have a license key which is valid for one installation.

In your case, yes, you need 5 one installation licenses or one 5 installation instances to run 5 instances at the same time.

You may also want to take a look at OEM or bulk licenses if you need to run many instances.

Hope this helps.